# How to append a letter to a resource file

Tags: java, android

The method `Picture` receives a random `int i`. I  want to add `i` to the `R.drawable.pic+i`
in order to randomly choose between several drawables in the resource folder (pic0,pic1,pic2,…) and set them as background at the end of the view `k`. How can I do it? Here's the code I have now:

```
public void Picture(int i){
    View k = new View(NewGame.this);
    k.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic); 
    // here it should be k.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pic1); for example
    setContentView(k);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code that worked for me is :

```
public void Picture(int i){

View k = new View(NewGame.this);

setContentView(k);

int resourceId=getResources().getIdentifier("pic"+i, "drawable",getPackageName()); 

k.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try as:

```
int resourceId=Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("pic"+1, "drawable", getPackageName());
k.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);
```

Comment: You helped me very much , thanx! but what worked in the end ( made a bit adjustments because your exact code didn't work for me ) is : `code int resourceId=getResources().getIdentifier("pic"+i, "drawable", getPackageName()); `
  k.setBackgroundResource(resourceId);

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like the [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method to get your resId.

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
public static String PACKAGE_NAME ;
PACKAGE_NAME=getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier( PACKAGE_NAME+":drawable/" + "pic"+urrandomenumber, null, null);  
k.setBackgroundResource(resID);
```